How i can read properties in input parameters in delegate?
I came across an interesting problem. At the moment, the dictionary Parameter Name + its type is passed from above. I wanted to decorate and simplify the code a little. But I can’t figure out what to grab onto.
I have a method:
private void MethodAnalyze(Func<dynamic, Test> method)
{
  Dictionary<string, type> dic <- here must be ["Id", int32], ["Address", string]
}

class Test
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public string Address {get;set;}
  public int Flat {get;set;}
}

MethodAnalyze(x => new Test{Id=x.Id, Address = x.Address}); //without Flat!!!

Is it possible?
I need to get information about the fields of the input parameter in order to implement further application logic. Everything else has already been done. I wanted to optimize this place.
Through reflection, for some reason I get an Object type that does not have the fields I’m interested in.
Thanks

EDITED
i have old project on .NET Framework 4.8. I wrote linq query on EF to Db. I want get not all properties of entity. Set of properties is dynamic (users set). I write RepositoryBase and I want write:
var list = query.Skip(skip).Take(page.PageSize)
.Select(lamba1).ToList() 

lamba1 - it is released Expression. Then
var result = list.Select(func1).ToList(); 

func1 - it is Func<dynamic, T>
This is the way I want to solve the problem: "The entity or complex type 'Test' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query".
It realy worked code:
Expression<Func<Test, dynamic>> lamba1 = s => new { s.Field1 };
Func<dynamic, Test> lamba2 = s => new Test{ Field1= s.Field1 }; 
var list = context.Test.Where(w => w.Field2 == null)
.Select(lamba1).ToList().Select(lamba2).ToList(); 

lamba1 - replaced realy method which generate Expression.
lamba2 - input parameter.
I want from lamba2 generate lamba1

The syntax x => Test{Id=x.Id, Address = x.Address} is invalid. Did you mean new Test { ... }? And just to be clear, you want dic to contain the property names that are accessed on x? Or do you want the names of the properties that are set? That is, what would dic contain for new Test{ Id=x.Foo, Address = x.Bar }?

Are you sure dynamic is better than using a generic type? What is the actual goal? If you want to do something with lambdas and reflection you might want to take a look at expression trees

@Sweeper yes: new Test { ... }. I want dic contains the property names that are accessed on x (not from Test, but property in x same in Test, but may be not all)?

So for new Test{ Id=x.Foo, Address = x.Bar }, the dic would be Foo: int, Bar: string?

@Sweeper yes. Without property Flat

I'm really confused about the requirement here. Do you have a fixed list of properties to add to the dynamic object and want to pass any possible object to retrieve those? Or do you have a fixed object type, and you want to pass a list of properties to add to dynamic? Or are both not fixed? Or perhaps you don't want dynamic at all, but want to recreate the same object type, just withonly a few properties copied? It doesn't help that your existing code is not compilable. How about you show us your actual existing code.

Please use the [edit] button to add that in, and explain further your exact situation. That is an entirely different problem. Linq to Entities cannot use dynamic at all, you need to use an Expression<Func<TSource, TResult>> instead.

Fascinating. I still don't think it's going to work but please use the [edit] button and put that in your post.

@Sweeper OR: new Test{ Id=x.Foo, Address = x.Bar }, the dic would be Id: int, Address: string
